# Initial BufferedImage and converted BufferedImage objects are not giving same result

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javacv, javax.imageio

I am writing a test process which will act as duplicate to original processors

My class will take a video file as input then generates frame related information

```
Java2DFrameConverter bufferedImgConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
String filePath = "Palivala.mp4";
File tsFile = new File(filePath);
FFmpegFrameGrabber ffmpegFrameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(tsFile);
OpenCVFrameConverter matConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();
ffmpegFrameGrabber.start();
try {
        while ((frame = ffmpegFrameGrabber.grabFrame(false, true, true, false)) != null) {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = bufferedImgConverter.convert(frame);
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte frameAsBytes[] = buffer.toByteArray();
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            BufferedImage bufferedImage2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameAsBytes));
            Mat mat = matConverter.convertToMat(bufferedImgConverter.convert(bufferedImage)); //problem is here, I explained problem at the bottom
            if (mat.empty())
                continue;
            if (prevMat != null) {
                // here I am generating required data and sending to the method which I want to test
            }
            prevMat = mat.clone();
            numProcessedFrames++;

        }
    } catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while grabbing frames for segment " + e);
    }
ffmpegFrameGrabber.stop();
```

If I use initial `BufferedImage` object(`bufferedImage`) its working as expected but when I use converted `BufferedImage` object(`bufferedImage2`) its not working as expected i.e actually my process finds info about frozen frames, If the video is frozen for 20seconds

- Its giving final output as 20seconds (if I use `bufferedImage` object)
- Its giving final output as 14seconds (if I use `bufferedImage2` object)

I am generating `standard-deviation` using `mat` object which is getting from

```
Mat mat = matConverter.convertToMat(bufferedImgConverter.convert(bufferedImage)); //it works fine

Mat mat = matConverter.convertToMat(bufferedImgConverter.convert(bufferedImage2)); its the problem
```

I am getting frozen-frame info using `standard-deviation` and my `standard-deviation-threshold` is `90`

- `standard-deviation` is continuously below `90` If I use `bufferedImage` object
- `standard-deviation` is continuously below `90` till 6 seconds then for 1 frame I am getting `standard-deviation` value as `[118.0, 118.0, 119.0]` then next frame again below `90` If I use `bufferedImage2` object

Comment: What happens if you write the original image as a PNG instead of a JPEG? Perhaps the lossy compression of JPEG creates noise that will interfere with your algorithm?

Comment: Thanks @haraldK, Its solved my problem. I have one more issue, i.e for `wmv ` files If video is frozen for 30seconds first 3secconds frozen then its showing 1 single unfrozen frame again next frame is frozen,due to this I am getting 27 seconds only instead of 30secconds, getting this issue whether I take `bufferedImage` or `bufferedImage2` Not getting this issue for `mp4` and `avi` files